# Is there a way to add a button to a accordion with devextreme angular?

Tags: angular, devextreme

I am using devextreme-angular and I would like to include two buttons such as DELETE and EDIT to accordion. The accordions receive the posts I typed so i have title and content for each accordion. What I need now is to add these buttons to each of the content with devextreme-angular.

I have tryied to add these buttons with dxi-item and dx-button inside the dx-accordion but none of them worked. Below is my accordion code on post-component.html file:

```
<dx-accordion
    [dataSource]="posts"
    [multiple]="true"
    noDataText="No posts available">
</dx-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo available at the Devextreme website that shows how to create a title template: https://js.devexpress.com/Angular/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Accordion/Overview/MaterialBlueLight/

So your HTML should look something like this:

```
 <dx-accordion
    [dataSource]="posts"
    [multiple]="true"
    noDataText="No posts available"
  >
    <!-- THIS IS THE TITLE TEMPLATE-->
    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'title'">
      <div class="title-container">
        <div class="header">{{ ITEM TITLE HERE }}</div>
        <div class="flex-after">
          <dx-button
            icon="trash"
            (onClick)="handleDeleteClick($event, data)"
          ></dx-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'item'">
     <!-- PUT YOUR ITEM TEMPLATE HERE -->
    </div>
  </dx-accordion>
```

TS:

```
  handleDeleteClick = (e, data) => {
    //IMPORANT SO ACCORDION ITEM DOESN'T TOGGLE
    e.event.stopPropagation();

    // DELETE LOGIC
  };
```

CSS:

```
.title-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-after {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

NOTE: You should never use dxi in dxTemplate. "dxi" stands for "DevExtreme Item." It's a shorthand used within DevExtreme Angular components to create and configure items within a container or collection component, such as a list, menu, or toolbar.